# Download other page using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there a way to download the page using javascript/ajax functions except for jQuery? 
It is not an option.

Comment: What do you mean by "download"? You can download pages with wget, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to downloading a html page served on another domain using ajax, then the answer is no. Due to security browsers does not allow that. Read more about that here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

You could probably solve this by using a service such as http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/ which uses [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing)

Comment: Why was this answer accepted? It's wrong. jQuery is just a framework built on top of JavaScript. You can do what the OP is asking in native JavaScript, or via one of the many other frameworks. Saying you need to use Yahoo Pipes is like saying you need a jumbo jet to get to the local supermarket. Andreas's answer is correct.

Comment: If you are going to say I'm mistaken then you should show us something that can verify it so that we can know for sure and learn from it.

Comment: As far I know there are only 2 ways to load data from another domain. 1. A Proxy such as pipes. 2. JSONP which needs the remote server to have that setup and enabled. Still the answer to OP's question would be no. But if you now another way which you can show us, I would really like to know! :)

Comment: @Ancide Sorry, I was referring to AJAX - I didn't see that the OP doesn't have any server-side language because it wasn't mentioned in the question. I withdraw my downvote, and apologise.

Comment: @Blowski No need to apologies. I think I speak for most of us here when I say that if someone knows something new or points something out that was missed it is most welcomed! :)

Comment: But the thing is, the OP just said "other page"; there was no indication of whether the page is on the same domain or not.
So I assumed that what he's asking for is to use AJAX without a framework, and that's what Blowski probably assumed as well, so I totally understand why there was this ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use the ol' [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: I know that it is possible to send a post and get requests via XMLhttpRequests, but can I download the source of other domain. I do not have any server side language available this time.

Comment: See my answer. It's not possible on another domain.

Comment: What about downloading xml and rss feeds?

Comment: It's the same thing there. It doesn't matter if it's a rss feed.

Comment: Well technically, you still need the `XMLHttpRequest` object, irrespective of whether the page is on the same domain or not.

But if it's not, you need to make a couple of modifications due to security issues and what have you,  and that's where Ancide's comes in.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using XMLHttpRequest if the page you're hitting is on the same domain. Just set the content type in the response to something like `application/force-download`.